# How to add css to 1 element when hiding another?.. Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hide, show

I'm trying to make a javascript, that hides/shows and element(which I did), now I would like to know if there's a way to add css to another element when the first element is hidden.

In short:
Ex. When div1 is hidden, add css to div2?

Ty in advance!

Woops, you're right.. forgot to add the code -_-
Here it is!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function(){
            $("#row-offcanvas").hide();

        });
        $("#show").click(function(){
            $("#row-offcanvas").show();
        });
        var isHidden  = $('#row-offcanvas').is(':hidden'); 

        --> add some css to #test (another div)

    });
```

Comment: Post some code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use add and remove class when showing/hiding your elements, but maybe you want to add it in the click function

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#row-offcanvas").hide();
        $( "element" ).addClass( "yourClass" );
});

$("#show").click(function(){
        $("#row-offcanvas").show();
        $( "element" ).removeClass( "yourClass" );
});
```

Comment: worked like a charm.. ty ty ty! Actually I thought about it earlier.. Don't know why I thought it wouldn't work :P lol

Answer (score 0):

You could fire an event when you hide the element and listen for that event. When the listener sees the event you fired you can add the css to that element. One way to do it. Add your code for a more involved answer.